# Connecting jumper wires through door

Tags: sensor, connection

I'm building a setup to measure the occupied surface of a trailer. In order to do this, I want to place several ultrasonic sensors (HC-SR04) on the swing doors. The setup is shown below, with the swing doors in light blue, the ultrasonic sensors in red, and the Raspberry Pi in black.

[image: Diagram of trailer showing sensor placement]

I then want to connect these ultrasonic sensors to a Raspberry Pi, which I will charge with a powerbank and a [Sleepy Pi](http://spellfoundry.com/product/sleepy-pi-2/). The Sleepy Pi should wake the Raspberry Pi at certain intervals, the Raspberry Pi can then do the measurements after which it will go back to sleep.

I don't really know how to connect the far two sensors, as any wires going through the door will prevent the door from opening. We have thought about placing the sensors at the swingdoor-roof intersection, but some preliminary tests showed that the performance of the ultrasonic sensors decreased significantly when the sensor is not perpendicular to the measurement object.

We have also thought about using two Pi's, but that would mean that we would have to buy another Raspberry Pi, power bank and Sleepy Pi, which doesn't seem like the best option.

Are there any good, or known solutions to this problem?

Comment: This is a case where if you tell us the overall problem you may well get better answers than having us try to solve your specific approach. Have you considered things like moving the Pi or the sensor? What are you trying to measure with the sensor? Have you considered using a second Pi or microcontroller to send the data to the Pi wirelessly?

Comment: @SteveRobillard, sorry, I wanted to keep things as specific as possible. I'll rewrite my question to include the overall problem.

Comment: I take it loads are not palletized (if they were you could count pallets which would likely be easier). Your idea to mount it near the roof, as for the inconsistent returns are you getting a consistent value but one that does not equate to the remaining space? If consistent readings are obtained you can solve the volume problem with some trigonometry.

Comment: Thanks for the input Steve. I'm not sure about the principles, but I think that as the ultrasonic sensors are relying on reflections, mounting them at an angle could cause the surface to reflect away from the sensor. We still have to do a real test on this, but some table testing showed that the range of the sensors was approximately 4m on perpendicular surfaces (as is given by the specs). Upon changing the surface angle, this distance greatly reduced (down to ~1m)

Comment: There are many solutions to this problem. But you are not asking Raspberry Pi specific question. You are asking for some advice, for a problem which sounds very interesting to solve, but is open ended and this should have been closed.

Answer (score 0):

If I am reading the issue right. Why not bring the wires below the door outside, or even come up from underneath? It may take a bit more wire and a couple of holes but should make it possible to open the doors without disturbing the wiring.

Comment: That would be a solution, but we would like to keep the system as portable as possible. Also, as this trailer is not ours, we would like to prevent any holes if possible.

Comment: You could simply tape down the wiring. But if no wires is all you can do then you are likely looking at a wireless/infrared system of some sort much like the remote control for a television. If you cannot have wires, then your only choice is infrared.